# Delete a row based on conditional value fill

Tags: vba, excel

> I am currently working on a database analysis and I have a Conditional format rule which fills a cell red. I need to delete the whole row for that cell which is red, I am able to do so if the cell is filled with that color manually but not through the conditional value rule, Here is what I have right now:

```
  Sub delteRed()

  Dim xRg As Range, rgDel As Range
  Sheets("Hoja1").Select
  For Each xRg In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A21")
    If xRg.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
        If rgDel Is Nothing Then
            Set rgDel = xRg
        Else
            Set rgDel = Union(rgDel, xRg)
        End If
    End If
Next xRg
If Not rgDel Is Nothing Then rgDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: You can create a Filter that filters by color, hiding those red rows. If you need to be rid of them completely, just copy the visible cells to a new page?  (Just an alternate solution to VBA).  Also, what's your conditional format rule that you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a VBA sub procedure you can use the [DisplayFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-displayformat-property-excel) to determine the color of a cell that has been adjusted by a CFR.

```
If xRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
```

[DisplayFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-displayformat-property-excel) cannot be used in a UDF.

Comment: Worked perfect!